# Xpages: how to do partial refresh correctly

Tags: xpages

I am trying to get a partial refresh to ONLY refresh the chunk of the page that I need to refresh. I understand that if I do a normal partial refresh the entire JSF lifecycle gets called. I understand that a way around this is to set "Set partial execution mode" and to select the ID I want to refresh.

However I can't get it to work.

Below I have put in a very simple example. When I put a value in the execID then I do not see the refreshed form row. When I don't put the execID in I DO see the values of the form rows, but I believe I am not doing a partial refresh.

I am not understanding something. Any help would be very much appreiciated.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:formRow id="flyApplication" labelPosition="inherit"
        label="Application(s)">
    <xp:checkBoxGroup id="field1" layout="lineDirection"
            styleClass="twoColumnCheckBoxGroup">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pnlModules" execMode="partial" execId="pnlModules">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var v = getComponent("field1").getValue();
print (v);}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
            <xp:selectItems>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["Yes","No"]}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:checkBoxGroup>
    </xe:formRow>
    <xp:panel id="pnlModules">
        <xe:formRow id="fr2" labelPosition="inherit"
            label="Module(s)">
            <xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:var v = getComponent("field1").getValue();
if (v == "Yes")
{return true}
else
{return false}}]]></xe:this.rendered>ddd<xp:checkBoxGroup id="field2" layout="lineDirection"
                styleClass="fourColumnCheckBoxGroup">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"a"}]]></xp:this.value>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Values" itemValue="Values"></xp:selectItem>
            </xp:checkBoxGroup>
        </xe:formRow>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial Execution requires that the control that triggers the event be inside the panel that is getting partially executed.

Keep in mind that partial refresh and partial execution are two different things but can be used together if you keep in mind what I said above.

Comment: There was a great session on this at MWLug.  Slides should be available somewhere.  I forget if it was Howards session or someone elses...

Comment: It was me and I am going to repeat the session in a webinar on Oct 15th, details at www.tlcc.com

Comment: Just to elaborate on Howard's answer, if the control that's running your SSJS/Java isn't in the area being partially executed, the XPages runtime will just be skipping that control and the code you want to run. I'm not sure if it still needs to be in the execution area if you're just doing a partial refresh with no code. R9 changed the defaults when it exposed partial execution in the Event Handler panel. Previously the default was the current component, but it's now the refreshId.